# Referrer header doesn't set when redirect with window.location in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, referrer

I'm trying to redirect to a third party page by using `window.location` in react. But when I made a redirect, third party server doesn't receive a referrer header from my redirect. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting or a web page can not set HTTP request headers.
if you want to use the header you have to make an async request using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Thank @Natapon i also would like to redirect to the user to the third party page. is XHR is only fetching resource from a url. is there anyway to redirect user to the third party page and also setting the request referrer header with my url.

Comment: you can make a request with header to your third party server.
and have your third party send you a html page.
I mean you can just request for your  third party page and render it

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
<form action="/target-page" method="get" name="redirect"></form>
<script> document.forms['redirect'].submit() </script>
```

source: https://coderwall.com/p/7a09ja/no-referer-after-redirect-solved